# index.html displays only some components after yarn build from create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Previously, opening index.html after running `yarn build` showed a blank page.

I managed to get it to display something by adding `"homepage": "./"` to my package.json.

Now it does show **something**, but there are quite a few components missing. Mainly it's not rendering any of the images that are located in src/data/images.

In addition to this, the browser shows the following error:

```
Access to internal resource at 'file:///Users/josephliu/workspace/speedlimit_signs/build/manifest.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, brave, chrome-untrusted, https.
```

Here's what my project folder looks like:

```
project/
  build/
  public/
  src/
    components/
    data/
      train_images/
      test_images/
```

Comment: Kindly share your code, can be several issues like not calling required component, giving false directory, or missing out routing etc.

Comment: Sure, here's the github link: https://github.com/drjosephliu/speedlimit_signs

Comment: I just added an update. There's a CORS error regarding the manifest.json

Answer (score 0):

Turns out [you can't use BrowserRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6533) (which is what I was using) with a file:// path. So I switched to HashRouter instead and it solved the problem